# Facebook app - cannot add "Facebook Login" product under products

Tags: facebook

I created an app in "Facebook Developers".
When I enter the Dashbord, I don't see "Facebook Login".
The "Products (+)" is grayed.
And there are NO products (Facebook Login) under it.
How do I add Facebook Login?

Comment: _“The "Products (+)" is grayed”_ - still clickable though. _“And there are products (Facebook Login) under it. How do I add Facebook Login?”_ - why do you want to add what’s already there?

Comment: I fixed the question - There are NO products under it.
I need to add a URL from firebase to the client in the Login product.
The "products (+) is clickable, but it just opens the same page as clicking the "dashboard".

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange but today, I re-entered the same facebook page. 
And again, clicked on the "products (+)" link.
To my surprize, now I see many products in the page.
I clicked on the "Facebook Login", and how I see it under the "Products".
So I clicked on it, and was finally able to set the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" (from firebase).
So basically, you just need to wait a day to do it.